# Getting WA, created own test cases too but not getting approved answers

Tags: c++

- **Link of Question :**  https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/PTMSSNG

**Question Statement**

Chef has N axis-parallel rectangles in a 2D Cartesian coordinate system. These rectangles may intersect, but it is guaranteed that all their 4N vertices are pairwise distinct.

Unfortunately, Chef lost one vertex, and up until now, none of his fixes have worked (although putting an image of a point on a milk carton might not have been the greatest idea after all…). Therefore, he gave you the task of finding it! You are given the remaining 4N−1 points and you should find the missing one.

***Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong or update my code or share a few test cases.***

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <utility>
    
    #define ll long long
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int t;
        cin >> t;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            vector<pair<ll, ll>> v;
            ll n, m, a;
            bool checkx = false;
            cin >> n;
            m = 4 * n - 1;
            ll x[m], y[m];
            ll c, d;
            a = (m - 1) / 2;
            for (ll i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                cin >> x[i] >> y[i];
                v.push_back(make_pair(x[i], y[i]));
            }
            sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    
            for (ll i = a; i >= 1; --i)
            {
                if (v[2 * i].first != v[2 * i - 1].first)
                {
                    c = v[2 * i].first;
                    checkx = true;
                    if ((2 * i) % 4 == 0 && i >= 2)
                    {
                        if (v[2 * i].second == v[2 * i + 1].second)
                        {
                            d = v[2 * i + 2].second;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            d = v[2 * i + 1].second;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (v[2 * i].second != v[2 * i - 1].second)
                        {
                            d = v[2 * i - 1].second;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            d = v[2 * i - 2].second;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (checkx)
            {
                cout << c << " " << d;
            }
            else
            {
                if (v[0].second == v[1].second)
                {
                    d = v[2].second;
                }
                else
                {
                    d = v[1].second;
                }
                cout << v[0].first << " " << d;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This solution looks overly complex.  Surely you just need to collect the `x` and `y` values into separate vectors and locate the value in each vector that appears an odd number of times.

Comment: Sure, I'll modify my complex code. Can you please provide some test cases where my code will not work.

Comment: You want me to: (A) analyze a program with no comments and unhelpful variable names; (B) identify possible points of failure; (C) engineer a test case to make it fail; (D) report back to you.  Sorry, but that really isn't how this website works.  You haven't even shown what test cases you currently have that work, or discussed in any detail what you've tried.  If I were you I would start by asking yourself exactly how sorting a vector of pairs works.  Could it perhaps be that you are making an incorrect assumption about whether searching immediately adjacent values is suitable?

Comment: `ll x[m], y[m];` -- First, usage of macros like `ll` makes the code hard to read.  Second, arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  Thus that line is not legal C++.  You have an `#include <vector>`, so you should be using it here:  `std::vector<long long> x(m), y(m);`.  Also, usage of that non-legal C++ syntax could blow out the stack memory if `m` is sufficiently large.  The bottom line is that you can't learn good C++ programming from "competition" websites like codechef.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do such complex things. Just input your `x` and `y` vectors and xor every element of each vector. The final value will be the required answer.

**LOGIC** :

```
(a,b)------------------(c,b)
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |                      |
(a,d)------------------(c,d)
```

See by this figure, each variable (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) occurs even number of times. This "even thing" will also be true for the `N` rectangles. Hence, you have to find the values of `x` and `y` which are occurring odd number of times.

To find the odd one out in such cases, the best trick is to xor every element of the vector. This works because of these properties of xor : `k xor k = 0` and `k xor 0 = k`.

**CODE:**

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

signed main() {
    std::size_t t, n;
    std::cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        std::cin >> n;
        n = 4 * n - 1;
        std::vector<int> x(n), y(n);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            std::cin >> x.at(i) >> y.at(i);
        std::cout << std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0L, std::bit_xor<int>()) << ' '
                  << std::accumulate(y.begin(), y.end(), 0L, std::bit_xor<int>()) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a test case that your code doesn't work:

```
1
2
1 1
1 4
4 6
6 1
9 6
9 3
4 3
```

the output of your code is `(6,3)`,but it should be `(6,4)`.
I guess you can check more cases where the rectangles intersects.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    li=[]
    li1=[]
    for i in range(4*n-1):
        m,n=map(int,input().split())
        li.append(m)
        li1.append(n)
    r =reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y,li)
    print(r,end=' ')
    r =reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y,li1)
    print(r,end=' ')
    print()
```